# What am I accessing through square brackets in a variable if they don't exist as a member?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Found some code that contains a variable that has a "property" accessed through square brackets `$item['PageLayoutType']`.

I was wondering why and what it is I'm accessing here. It's not really a property, is it? Otherwise it should appear in `| Get-Member` right?

The variable was created through some SharePoint Pnp PowerShell:

```
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List 'SitePages' -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>Home1.aspx</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

How can I find out what else I can put in the square brackets? Nothing that is retrieve by `Get-Member` works in them.

Comment: Try `$item | Format-List -Property *` or `$item | Select-Object -Property *`

Comment: It seems a hash table (or dictionary, if you prefer). Those square brackets parts are keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$object = @{
    first = "1"
    second = "2"
    third = @{
        fourth = "4"
        fifth = "5"
        sixt = @{
            seventh = "6"
        }
    }
}
```

It's a hashtable like the above example.

```
$object | Get-Member
```

Will give you the properties but not the underlying values.

You can find the values like:

```
$object.first.fourth.seventh
```

Or:

```
$object["first"]
```

Or:

```
$object["third"]["sixt"]["seventh"]
```

An easy way to see and understand the complete object is to simply convert it to JSON:

```
$object | ConvertTo-Json
```

This will output the complete object and if it is still not showing everything use the -Depth parameter.